# Potential difference on a curcuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

[image: Circuit]

Above is a simple circuit.  It has a voltage of 9V between the two terminals.  I have drawn red lines which look like vectors, indicating how the current will flow.  From the above diagram, I have a few questions:

When I talk about potential difference along a path, I'm referring to the potential of the vectors tip minus the potential of the vectors tail.

Can someone tell me if the potential difference is 0, increases, or decreases (even if by very little, a negligible amount) as the current flows along ABCDE?

If I were to guess, I would say that

Along A, the potential difference decreases.  Along B, is 0.  Along C, it decreases.  Along D, it is 0.  And along E, it also decreases.

Comment: Does that blue line indicate some kind of closed circuit of a conductor?  So, is this a short-circuit.  Technically, the potential difference across a short circuit is zero.  If it were an open circuit (that is current flow is zero) then the potential difference is 9 volts.

Comment: If your lines indicate ideal wires, then your model is inconsistent. You must include either the internal resistance of the battery, or the resistance of the wires, or both, to adequately model such a circuit.